# I new a Android Test Project and Select Test Target “This project”, but I dont get an empty src directory and instead get an unexpected package

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, apk, robotium

I want to use `robotium` to test android apk.

I have the full android IDE (`Eclipse/ADT/Java SDK/Android SDK`), so I can use `File--New--Other...--Android Test Project` to create my test Project `MyApKTest`.

Now I get the page `Select Test Target` and have two choices:

- This project
- An existing Android project.

Because I want to test apk and don't have the source code, I chose `This project` and then chose the build target.

And the problem comes:

I supposed I will get an empty project. However, when I step into the `src` of `MyApkTest`, I see an unexpected package `com.calculator.test`. In fact I have a project naming `com.calculator`, but I chose `This project` instead of `An existing Android project`.

Why have I got this package? Although the package is empty itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old eclipse issue. It always creates last used (created) package in Android Test Project. If it cannot find any it creates "com.example.android.apis.tests" package. Anyway I don't know where it's stored.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems that I have to start my project by editing the default package now. Thanks to @alecxe for your help to improve my question. As a newcomer I didn't pay attention to the format. I will notice it in the future. Thanks a lot.